# How can I allow user to submit a form

Tags: python, django

When I try to submit `Table` model to the database using `create_table` view, it throws me an error: `NOT NULL constraint failed: audioApp_table.user_id` after I do my own research I found out it was because I didn't add user to the form, so I try to add it by adding: `table = Table(user=request.user)`, but it is not working, how can we allow user to submit this form, I knew how to do that in `class base view` using `instance.user = self.request.user`, but for `function base view` I'm failed.

```
def create_table(request):
    columns = Column.objects.filter(user=request.user)

    fields = {}
    for column in columns:
        if column.field_type.data_type == 'number':
            fields[column.name] = forms.IntegerField()

        elif column.field_type.data_type == 'character':
            fields[column.name] = forms.CharField(max_length=20)

        elif column.field_type.data_type == 'decimal':
            fields[column.name] = forms.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=10)

        elif column.field_type.data_type == 'image':
            fields[column.name] = forms.ImageField()

        elif column.field_type.data_type == 'boolean':
            fields[column.name] = forms.BooleanField()

        elif column.field_type.data_type == 'date':
            fields[column.name] = forms.DateField()
    TableForm = type('TableForm', (forms.Form,), fields)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = TableForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

        if form.is_valid():

            table = Table()

            for column in columns:
                setattr(table, column.name, form.cleaned_data[column.name])
                table.save()
                return redirect('Table')
    else:
        form = TableForm()
    return render (request, 'create_table.html', {'form':form})
```

```
class Table(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    number = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    decimal = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=10, blank=True, null=True)
    image =  models.ImageField(upload_to='table-image', blank=True, null=True)
    character = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    check_box = models.BooleanField(blank=True, null=True)
    date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the user for the Table instance before saving it to the database. You can do this by setting table.user to request.user after creating the table instance in your create_table view function

```
 if request.method == 'POST':
        form = TableForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

        if form.is_valid():
            table = Table()
            table.user = request.user 

            for column in columns:
                setattr(table, column.name, form.cleaned_data[column.name])

            table.save()
            return redirect('Table')
    else:
        form = TableForm()

    return render(request, 'create_table.html', {'form': form})
```